# Replacing values of a dataframe by upper bound of intervals if the values of the dataframe belong to the same interval

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe main_df. I have generated half open or semi closed intervals given a step size 1. The data and code are as follow.

```
mainList= [[0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.2],
      [0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.1], 
      [0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0. , 0.2, 0.3, 0. ],
      [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0. , 0.2, 0.2, 0.1],
      [0.2, 0.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0. , 0.2, 0.2, 0. ],
      [1.2, 0.1, 0.8, 2.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0. , 0.2, 0.1, 0.1],
      [1.3, 0.3, 0.2, 2. , 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0. ], 
      [1.3, 0.3, 0.2, 2.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0. ],
      [1.2, 0.2, 0.2, 2.6, 0.2, 2. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0. ],
      [1.2, 0.9, 0.2, 3.1, 1.9, 1.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1]]

main_df = pd.DataFrame(mainList)

val_min = min(main_df.min())
x = np.arange(val_min, val_max, 1)
interval_list = []
if len(x)/2 == 0:

     for i in range(0, len(x)):
         x1 = list(x[i:i+2])
         interval_list.append(x1)


else:
    for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
        x1 = list(x[i:i+2])
        interval_list.append(x1)

half_open_intervalsList = []
for j in interval_list:
    k = pd.Interval(j[0], j[1])
    half_open_intervalsList.append(k)
```

List of semi open Intervals look like as follows:

```
[(0.0, 1.0], (1.0, 2.0], (2.0, 3.0]]
```

I wanna replace the values of mainList/ main_df by the upper bound of the intervals if the values belong the same intervals. Note that the values in mainList remain as they are if they do not belong to these intervals.

I tried the following snippet but it's not outputting the desired result as given in outputList.

```
for ls in mainList:
for m in ls:
    sub_list = []
    for interval in range(0, len(half_open_intervalsList)):
        if m in half_open_intervalsList[interval]:
            #print(m)
            z = main_df.replace(element, half_open_intervalsList[interval].right)
            #sub_list.append(z)

outputList= [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 1], 
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 0. ],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 0. ],
      [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0. , 1, 1, 1],
      [2, 1, 1, 2 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. ], 
      [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. ],
      [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2 , 1, 1, 1, 0. ],
      [2, 1, 1, 3.1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping series from the list of half open intervals then use `.apply` + `map` to map the values in dataframe with the corresponding values from the mapping series, finally fill the `NaN` values(*values which can't be mapped*) with the values from original dataframe:

```
m = pd.Series([i.right for i in half_open_intervalsList], half_open_intervalsList)

main_df.apply(lambda s: s.map(m)).fillna(main_df)
# OR main_df.stack().map(m).unstack().fillna(main_df)
```

---

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
5  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
6  2.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
7  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
8  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
9  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.1  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```